# Long Polling, Apache Stuck when sleep() due to usage of sessions

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, long-polling

> Update: The usage of the sessions **is** the problem when calling the polling page because it's already open one time.

I'm doing a long polling on my web app.

For now i'm just doing something like: (the final goal is do a query then sleep, then a query, then sleep,...)

```
sleep(10);
echo 'ok';
```

on my server side (just to test it)

The issue : when i try then to load another page it's always taking **10 seconds**.

Comment: How many threads and processes does Apache have going?  There's a decent chance you're using all of Apache's resources and it's having to wait until a request finishes to serve a new one.

Comment: Yep. `sleep()` will tie up the Apache worker. Good way to denial-of-service yourself out of existence.

Comment: ahah ok... another way to do it without using sleep then, the goal is to query a data base every now and then to check if there is new stuff but between my queries i should us something like sleep if not the server will... explode ;)

Comment: I'm really working on that for... a long time :/

Comment: run the script as a cron every x minutes

Comment: Are you using sessions? The default file-based handler will lock the session file while a script is using it, preventing any parallel session-using requests from occuring at all.

Comment: Marc B looks like you're right, i did another page pull.php to test if it was calling by index.php the problem, it seems to solve it then i did my session_start(); in it and stuck... any work around for this or idea? I'm really stuck big time on this :(

Comment: There's some more useful information on this from a question I asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730857/long-polling-with-php-on-apache

Comment: yes it's definitely the polling page with the session_start that makes everything crash, so one of the solution which will be painful and stupid is to manage to work this polling page without using any session. I see nothing else for now. Thanks again Marc B for this big hint ;)

Comment: @jeron: use `session_write_close()` to relinquish the session within the sleeping script. The $_SESSION data will still be available for reading.

Comment: ok that solved my problem, thanks again you can post it as an answer. Alone i'll have spend days figuring the problem i think (i've already spend 7/9 hours on it)... I'm really glad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use session_write_close() to relinquish the session within the sleeping script. The $_SESSION data will still be available for reading. by **Marc B**