# receiving data from sockets in php

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I have transmitter and receiver applications, which sends continuous log data on TCP sockets.

I want these log data to publish on web, using PHP.

On PHP web server, I want to listen (socket listening) for TCP connections from transmitter and receiver, when they connects, I want to receive data from both, and then publish on web. Log data will be sent from apps continously at say 1 second interval.

How can I do this? Is there any better way to do this? If better, I will change transmitter and receiver apps.

I thought to send data as HTTP requests to web server, but wouldn't it cause overhead of TCP connection opening and closing every second, also from 2 apps, so opening and closing 2 TCP connections every second. And also may be that gives overhead to transmitter and receiver apps..

Is there anything by which I can send data as HTTP requests, but TCP connection do not get closed...

Thanks

Comment: I asked something similar last year and found that PHP does not work well with long polling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730857/long-polling-with-php-on-apache

Comment: How about sending log data as HTTP requests?